# Almost complex structure parallel with respect to non-Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Can an almost Kaehler structure $(M,g,J)$ be shown to be integrable (Kaehler) but using some non-Levi-Civita linear/affine connection? (E.g. finding a $\hat \nabla$ of the form $\hat \nabla = \nabla^{LC} + T$ such that $\hat \nabla J = 0$).

Comment: With another connection, you can show that $(M,J)$ is holomorphic (by showing that the Nijenhuis tensor of $J$ vanishes) but this will not relate with $g$, and hence will not give you any information on the Kaehler structure

Comment: Thank you! I have almost no experience with complex geometry. I have learned about Kaehler saying that it is a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, with an integrable complex structure $J$ which is compatible in the sense that $g(X,Y):=\omega(X,JY)$ is a riemannian metric. So for me the role of the Levi-Civita connection did not appear explicitly.

Comment: So using another connection one gets holomorphic local coordinates $(z_1,...,z_n)$, but that are not necessarily adapted to the splitting in eigenspaces induced by $J$? Is it easy to see that the Levi-Civita is the unique connection inducing compatible holomorphic coordinates?

Comment: One can use any torsion-free connection as a tool to show that the Nijenhuis tensor of $J$ vanishes. This will induce complex coordinates $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ that are indeed adapted to $J$. However, for $(M,g,J)$ to be Kahler, one has to check that $d\omega = 0$ where $\omega(X,Y) = g(JX,Y)$, which is equivalent to $\nabla J = 0$ where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection.

Comment: Thanks. It helps!